# Google cloud object persists after deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Chrome (vs Cloud SDK / command line) to repeatedly replace a file in a bucket. Dragging / dropping a file to overwrite the existing one, and / or deleting it first and putting it back (changed).

At a certain point the file stops updating and remains in a persistent state, even if I literally rm -r its parent folder.

i.e., I could have `/bucket/css/file.css` and rm -r `/bucket/css` and the file will still be available to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second answer, it seems that your bucket has the option of “Object Versioning” enabled.

When [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) is enabled for a bucket, Cloud Storage creates an archived version of an object each time the live version of the object is overwritten or deleted.
To verify that “Object Versioning” is enabled on your bucket you can use the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#check):

gsutil versioning get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

The response looks like the following if Object Versioning is enabled:

gs://[BUCKET_NAME]: Enabled

However, according to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/ObjectVersioningandConcurrencyControl#object-versioning) there is no limit to the number of older versions of an object you will create if you continue to upload to the same object in a versioning-enabled bucket.

Having said that, I tried to reproduce your case in my own bucket. The steps I followed are:

1.Enable Object Versioning for my bucket

2.Upload a file in the bucket with the name “example.png”, using the GCP Console.

3.Drag and drop another file with the same name (“example.png”), but different content.

4.Check option “Replace existing object”

5.Check if the file has been updated. It had.

6.Repeated the process 50 times (since you said you had 40 archived versions of your file) by uploading the different files one after the other, every time overriding the previous one. Each time I uploaded a different content file, a new archived version of that file was created. Each time file updated accordingly without any problems.

Please review the steps I followed and let me know if there is any additional action from your side.

Since you are able to delete the files via gsutil command, deletion is working fine and you have all permissions required. Would you be able to clean-up the cookies of your web browser, and try deleting it again? You can also try to use incognito window mode to check if its working.

Furthermore, if Object Versioning is on, you can [disable it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#disable) and try deleting the object again.Note that [object deletion](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects) can not be undone and once you delete the object it will be completely removed.

Additionally, a good practice suggested along with Object Versioning is to create an Object Lifecycle rule for the bucket that would delete all the objects that have been stored for more than a specific amount of time. You can use this as a workaround for deleting either live or archived versions of your object (if Object Versioning is actually enabled) and to accomplish it, you can follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable).

Generally, you can review Deleting data best practices [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting).

Note that, according to [Cloud Storage Object Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) a single particular object can only be updated or overwritten up to once per second. For more information, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Some in devops at our company created a policy on my bucket to disable object versioning.

Answer (score 0):

I used the gsutil to delete it and it worked... temporarily. It seems there were like 40 cached versions of the file with hash tag ids.

At some point it stops updating / deleting the file. :(

`gsutil rm -r gs://bucket/path/to/folder/`